# Switching to different camera if one fails to enable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv

I am doing an Android application with OpenCV and this is my problem:

I have two `JavaCameraView` elements in my main layout, one with frontal camera and the other with back camera. My idea is that in the Activity do a `try` `catch` situation to load the frontal camera and if it produces error load the back camera.

This is my conflited code:

```
try{ mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();}
catch() {
    Log.i(TAG,"frontal camera fails");
    //mOpenCvCameraView=mOpenCvCameraView2;
    //mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
}
```

What would be my exception?

Comment: the documentation of the method should tell you. and NPE in case `mOpenCvCameraView` can be null. or you could catch `Exception` but that should not be preferred if you know the exceptions that can be thrown

Comment: Sorry but I don´t understand very well, if you could me more details... thanks